# Set php variable equal to value of table cells generated from "while($row = mysql_fetch_array"

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, variables, while-loop

I have a php page that pulls data from a mysql database based on a select box. This is acheived by having a seperate php page handling the mysql queries. Javascript is then used to display this result on the original page without refreshing each time.

Each drop down list has 5 mysql fields returned in a single row from the mysql query.

I need to perform some logic based on the selected options and as such need to store each returned mysql field value as a unique variable that i can refernce on the next page.

How can I set this variable without have an ID to reference using the $_POST method? Is there another method of doing this?

My code for my two pages is displayed below, if anyone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

**index.php**

```
<html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function showUser(userNumber, str) 
  { 
  document.getElementById("r"+(userNumber+1)).style.display="block";  
    if (str=="") 
    { 
      document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=""; 
      return; 
    }   
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 
    else 
    {// code for IE6, IE5 
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    } 

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
    { 
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
      { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
      } 
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q="+str,true); 
    xmlhttp.send(); 
  } 
</script> 

 </head>
 <body>
 <?

 $con = mysql_connect('localhost', DBUser', 'DBPass');
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("DBName", $con);


$skusql="SELECT packcode,concat(packcode, ' - ' , description) as description from skudata"; 
$resultsku=mysql_query($skusql); 

$optionssku=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultsku)) { 

    $sku=$row["packcode"]; 
    $description=$row["description"]; 
    $optionssku.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$sku\">".$description; 
} 

 ?>

<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td width=393>Product</td>
    <td width=200>Category</td>
    <td width=150>Selling Unit</td>
    <td width=150>Grouping</td>
    <td width=150>Full Case QTY</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr id="r1">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(1, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint1"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="r2" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(2, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint2"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="r3" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(3, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint3"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="r4" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(4, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint4"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="r5" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(5, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint5"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r6" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(6, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint6"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r7" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(7, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint7"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r8" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(8, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint8"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r9" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(9, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint9"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r10" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(10, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint10"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
 </html>
```

**GetData1.php**

```
<?php
 $q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'DBUser', 'DBPass');
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("DBName", $con);

$sql="SELECT Category, SellingUnits,Grouping,CasesPerPallet,ShrinksPerPallet  FROM skudata WHERE packcode = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "<table border=1><tr>";
   echo "<td width=200>".$row['Category']."</td>";
   echo "<td width=150>".$row['SellingUnits']."</td>";
   echo "<td width=150>".$row['Grouping']."</td><td width=150>";
   if($row['SellingUnits']=="CS"){echo $row['CasesPerPallet'];} elseif($row['SellingUnits']=="SHR") {echo $row['ShrinksPerPallet'];}
   echo "</td></tr></table>";
   }

mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: Building hidden inputs for the values you want to work with is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create `<input type='hidden' value='xxxx'>` fields for each value you want to work with when the page is posted, and update those along with the table cells via javascript.  Then you will have the values to work with in your $_POST data.